# Setting render layer (Foreground, Character and Background in its own renderlayer) with Python

Tags: python, render, maya

I've been stuck in figuring out how to split the environment into foreground and background. I've been thinking of getting the value of "distance from camera" (through "display > heads up display > object details") so I can use it to split into foreground and background using the value of distance character from camera as a guide.

The problem is that I don't know how to get it's value in python. So can someone help me please?

I'm using Maya 2016.

I got "none" in this command :

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

print cmds.headsUpDisplay('HUDObjDetDistFromCam', q=1)
```

Comment: please show us what have you tried until now, do not just describe your idea

Comment: The best place to start on a first Q is with this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i uploaded the image to describe my problem, is it enough? :o

Comment: is it possible to get the value from it? i saw headsUpDisplay is queryable, and editable in maya help. @Gio

Comment: i got the code in MEL,
$result = `headsUpDisplay -q -sr HUDObjDetDistFromCam`;
but still stuck in python

Comment: okay thank you i got it lol

Comment: you can use this command to get the value from it

import maya.cmds as cmds

print cmds.headsUpDisplay('HUDObjDetDistFromCam', q=1, sr=1)[0]

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to hijack object distance from camera, you can just calculate it yourself.

```
import math
import maya.cmds as cmds

def distance_to_camera(obj, cam):
    cam_pos = cmds.xform(cam, t=True, ws=True, q=True)
    object_pos = cmds.xform(obj, t=True, ws=True, q=True)
    raw_dist = [a-b for a, b in zip(cam_pos, object_pos)]
    return math.sqrt (sum([a**2 for a in raw_dist]))
```

distance_to_camera('pCube1', 'persp')

`raw_dist = [a-b for a, b in zip(cam_pos, object_pos)]` is taking two lists of 3 numbers (the positions) and subtracting each item in one list from it's opposite number in the other.

`math.sqrt (sum([a**2 for a in raw_dist]))` is the square root of the squares of the three numbers in `raw_dist` -- that is, the distance.  You can do this using the Maya API but this version doesn't require any extra imports beside `math`

Comment: I don't think the value it displays in the HUD's Distance From Camera is actually a straight up distance, but instead the object's z-depth from the camera. For example create a camera in world origin and create a sphere 5 units away so it's visible in the camera. Now if the sphere moves side to side or up and down the distance from camera will remain as 5. So getting the object's raw distance will likely yield a different number.

Comment: Hmmm... a spherical distance would probably work for the OP's use case, but it would also be possible to repro the camera matrix and use that.  There's also the problem of whether to use pivot points or object centroids as the "distance" metric too.  But given the context of the Q I suspect a simple method is all thats needed

Comment: That's a good point. It might be safer to use the bounding box's centroid than the geometry's position, especially for any objects with deformers.